# Which data structure to use for keeping a list unique with insertion order intact

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I need to add objects to a list (with `List` semantics) while keeping all objects in the list unique. I figured `LinkedHashSet` would do, but the "re-insert" clause breaks this:

```
LinkedHashSet<String>list = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("a");
list.add("a");
System.out.println (list);
```

Output from the above is: `[a, b, c]`, not `[b, c, a]` as I would like it.

Is there any such data-structure in Java which handles this case?

Comment: And what's the expected behavior? This doesn't allow duplicates.

Comment: Why would you expect the output to be `[b, c, a]`? LinkedHashSet maintains the insertion order, and hence that output.

Comment: I think the op wants last insertion order (if a key is reinserted its position should change to a new position).

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR TreeSet does not maintain _insertion_ order.

Comment: @m0skit0 Expected behavior is detailed in my question (list semantics + set uniqueness).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
    Set<String> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean>(16, 0.75f, true));
    set.add("a");
    set.add("b");
    set.add("c");
    set.add("a");
    set.add("a");
    System.out.println(set);
```

output

```
[b, c, a]
```

Comment: It is a great idea, but worth mentioning that a get will also change the order.

Comment: @assylias Yes, but `Set` has no get(), so it works. This is a very clever idea.

Comment: @MartinWickman You are totally right - my comment makes no sense. I had given a +1 anyway.

Comment: What does the boolean do?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an out of the box data structure that does what you want as it seems a little odd. I would suggest you create a wrapper around LinkedHashSet that pops the element when you try to re-inserts it and than inserts it again.

Comment: *"create a **rapper**"*? :)

Comment: @m0skit0 ahahah just one of those typos that make typing so much fun thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is an out of the box data structure provided by the JDK libraries. If you look at this `LinkedHashMap` constructor:

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty <tt>LinkedHashMap</tt> instance with the
 * specified initial capacity, load factor and ordering mode.
 *
 * @param  initialCapacity the initial capacity
 * @param  loadFactor      the load factor
 * @param  accessOrder     the ordering mode - <tt>true</tt> for
 *         access-order, <tt>false</tt> for insertion-order
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the initial capacity is negative
 *         or the load factor is nonpositive
 */
public LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity,
                     float loadFactor,
                     boolean accessOrder) {
    super(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
    this.accessOrder = accessOrder;
}
```

there is an extra parameter `accessOrder`. Based on this, a newly added object will be moved to the end of the list (`accessOrder - true`) or remain at the old location (`accessOrder - false`).

In order to create a `Set` with these characteristics, you would need to use this factory method from `java.util.Collections`: `newSetFromMap(LinkedHashMap(initialCapacity, loadFactor, accessOrder))`

Keep in mind that the `accessOrder` property is responsible for **all** interactions with given element - if you'd call `get` on `HashMap` it will do reordering as well (that shouldn't affect you anyway because the `Set` interface does not expose a `get` method on a wrapped `HashMap`, just saying).